# Returning different values for rows

Tags: reactjs, state, react-props

I'm working on a take-home problem, and I can't figure out how to return different values for different rows. I am fairly new with react. I want this radio button to return the stated color value, but I want each row to be able to return different values. Here is the code.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';



class Applet extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {color: undefined};
  }
  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      color: event.target.value
    });
  }

  render() {
    const ColorBox = () => {

  return (
    <div className="row">
      <div className="col-sm">
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="color_r" value="red" checked={this.state.color === 'red'} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} /> R
            </label>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="color_g" value="green" checked={this.state.color === 'green'} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} /> G
            </label>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="color_b" value="blue" checked={this.state.color === 'blue'} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} /> B
            </label>
      </div>
      <div className="col-sm" >
        I am {this.state.color}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
let rows = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  rows.push(<ColorBox />);
}

return (
  <div className="whatthe">
    {rows}
  </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Applet />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

When I clicked on one radio button, it changed the target value for all of them. I think I understand why, but I don't know how to change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 solutions.

You can either make `ColorBox` a statefull component that will manage the color it has by itself.

Or store each color for every row into a different state value. I implemented the second solution in the code below.

`ColorBox` is now a stateless component that will get its current color and the handler function in its props. The handler function will be decorated with the index it has to set the correct value in your state.

Using computed properties you can now set the correct value in your state dynamically :

```
    handleChange = index => event => {
        this.setState({
            [index]: event.target.value
        });
    }
```

Fully working example :

```js
class Applet extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {  };
    }

    handleChange = index => event => {
        this.setState({
            [index]: event.target.value
        });
    }

    render() {
        

        let rows = [];

        for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            rows.push(<ColorBox colorSelected={this.handleChange(i)} color={this.state[i]}/>);
        }

        return (
            <div className="whatthe">
                {rows}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const ColorBox = ({ colorSelected, color }) => {
    return (
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col-sm" style={{ 'background-color': color }}>
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="color_r" value="red" checked={color === 'red'} onChange={colorSelected} /> R
                        </label>
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="color_g" value="green" checked={color === 'green'} onChange={colorSelected} /> G
                        </label>
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="color_b" value="blue" checked={color === 'blue'} onChange={colorSelected} /> B
                        </label>
            </div>
            <div className="col-sm" >
                I am {color}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

ReactDOM.render(
    <Applet />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'>
```

You will also need to give your radio buttons different `id`s depending of their group to avoid rendering problems

Comment: Looks great! One follow-up that I can't quite get my head around. How would I go about using the state to change the background color of the surrounding div? Every solution I try just sets everything to blank.

Comment: You have 2 solutions for this too. Either use the `style` attribute on your div to include some inline CSS and directly set the background color depending on your color props. Or you can set a given `className` to your div depending on the color props and set your CSS rules in an other file

Comment: You mean like <div className="row" style='background-color: {color}' >? I tried doing an if else statement like this if (color === 'red){this.style.background-color = red} and it just set everything to blank

Comment: You were close, the `style` prop requires a JSON containing your CSS rules, just edited my snippet

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You use the same state for each sub component. Make ColorBox in a component outside your Applet component.

Comment: Could you provide more specifically what you mean? I am trying to learn.